# Книга про технологию AJAX

Tags: ajax, книги

какую книжку лучше почитать об AJAX так как я новичок в этом пока ничего не понимаю было бы приятно если бы книга была бы написана подроно заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP и Ajax разработка динамических веб приложений.

Ну а так, возьми почитай в нете, инфы море, причем можешь сразу Jquery начать юзать :) много проще будет сразу.

Тогда так. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: в том то и дело я JQuery юзаю а вот в аяксе еще не разобрался

Comment: плюс Jquery

Comment: обновил ответ